# 2-adic valuation of $5^{2^{k-2}}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

I have the following exercice :

1. Consider that the 2-adic valuation of $x$ is $k \geq 2$. Prove that the 2-adic valuation of $(1+x)^2- 1$ is $k+1$.
2. Using the previous question, conclude that for $k\geq 2$, the 2-adic valuation of $5^{2^{k-2}}-1$ is $k$.

For the first l question, we know that $(1+x)^2 - 1= x(x+2) $. So, $$v_2((1+x)^2-1) = v_2(x)+\min(v_2(x),v_2(2))= k+1.$$

For the last question, I tried several methods but didn't work. Can someone give me a hint please?

Thanks!

Comment: In 1. you meant $k\ge 2$ as $v_2( (1-2)^2-1)=\infty$.

Comment: @reuns there was something wrong here when I edited the question. Look at it now

Comment: No try with $x=-2$ and $v_2((1+x)^2-1) = v_2(x)+v_2(x+2)$ was correct.

Comment: @reuns thanks! do I have to factor $5^{2^{k-2}} - 1$ if I want to solve the second question

Comment: No just apply 1.

Comment: @reuns ok, so $v_2(5^{2^{k-2}}-1)= v_2((1+x)^{2^{k-2}}-1)$ (here x = 4)  $\leq v_2((1+x)^{{2^{min(k-2)}}}-1) = v_2((1+x)-1) = v_2(x) = k $. Right?

Comment: Corrected question 1.  Should not affect question 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If $v_2(x)=k\ge 2$ then $v_2(x+2)=1$ and $v_2( (1+x)^2-1)=v_2 (x(x+2)) =v_2 (x)+v_2(x+2) =k+1$.
2. Let $x_{k+2}=5^{2^k}-1=(1+x_{k+1})^2-1, v_2(x_2)=2$, by induction if $v_2(x_k)=k$ then $v_2(x_{k+1})=k+1$.